# Using strcat() as a parameter to a function

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

Assume I call a function `void foo (char* fileName);` with the following call

```
foo("file.txt");
```

Is it ok to call `foo()` with:

```
foo(strcat("file.txt",".binary"));
```

Will it cause any memory problems? As I understand the only problem I can face is a stack overflow, right?

Comment: You're not really concating two string literals together, are you? What's your actual code?

Comment: @TimCooper, There is no actual code, I was just wondering if I use `strcat()` while using `fopen()` for example, will cause a stack error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it cause any memory problems?

Yes, this is undefined behavior, so it may cause a crash.

> As I understand the only problem I can face is a stack overflow, right?

No, the problem here is that `strcat` will attempt to write past the end of string literal.

You can fix your program as follows:

```
// Copy into writable memory, and give enough space to fit ".binary"
char fileTxt[16] = "file.txt";
foo(strcat(fileTxt,".binary"));
```

Also, with string literals the compiler will do concatenation for you if you simply put them one after the other:

```
foo("file.txt" ".binary");
```

Comment: @Quaker Yes, this is part of the standard, section 6.4.5.7.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, for `strcat`, the first parameter will be used to store the result, so it must be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

In your example, the first parameter is a string literal, which can't be modified, not to say having enough space.

Answer (score 1):

It will crash; under OSX, I get:

```
$ ./a.out
Abort trap: 6
```

With the following stack trace:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8ad85866 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff83cb136c pthread_kill + 92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8455dbba abort + 125
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8455dd31 abort_report_np + 181
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff845818c5 __chk_fail + 48
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff845818d5 __chk_fail_overlap + 16
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff845818f7 __chk_overlap + 34
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84581c29 __strcat_chk + 81
8   a.out                           0x0000000105c63f09 main + 57
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8f2255fd start + 1
```

You are attempting to copy over a string constant, which will often be located in readonly memory.

Answer (score 1):

The initial byte of the second string overwrites the null byte of the first. So the first string (apart from not being a string literal as mentioned above) should be large enough to hold all characters of both strings plus the end of string character. Moreover, the strings should not overlap.